# Using HBase Shell to check cell level TTL

Tags: hbase, cell, ttl

I know I can check the column family level TTL using 'describe' on the table. Is there a similar shell command to get the TTL set on Cell level?

This answer talks about the ability to retrieve it via the HBase API, but not from the HBase shell, so I believe there should be a way to check that on the shell as well.

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Get-ttl-from-HBase-record/td-p/32224

Comment: Any success on this ?

Answer (score -2):

Well HBase Shell `describe` shows the schema for each Column family, incluing the TTL when set

Comment: I already mentioned that i can get that from "describe" but for column family not cell level TTL.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. So you are using custom TTL on cells which may be different from Column family TTL ?

Comment: Yes, I am setting the TTL's on Cell level presently, and I have no TTL set on the Column Family level.